# Coloring simple graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph with $5$ vertices and $6$ edges. Find the chromatic number and polynomial.

[image: graph]

The chromatic number is trivial, it would of course be $3$. But I am completely clueless on how to find the chromatic polynomial. I know there's no effective algorithm, but is there any shortcut to these graphs, such as there is with complete graphs?

Comment: I explained the calculation of the chromatic polynomial in detail in [Calculating Total Number of Possible 4-Colorings of a Graph](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/773309/25554). The only difference is that there I took $\chi(\bullet) = 4$ and for the general polynomial you want to take $\chi(\bullet) = n$ to get a polynomial in $n$. The algorithm takes a long time to run *on large graphs* but on your tiny graph you can easily execute it by hand in a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Fundamental Reduction Theorem many times. It states that

$$P(G,t)=P(G-uv,t)-P(G/uv,t)$$
where $u$ and $v$ are two adjacent vertices, $G-uv$ is the graph obtained by removing the edge $uv$ and $G/uv$ is the graph obtained by contracting the vertices $u$ and $v$.

After two times you should obtain
$$ P(P_5,t)-P(P_4,t)-P(P_4,t)+P(P_3,t), $$
where $P_j$ is the path graph with $j$ vertices.

You know that the chromatic polynomial for a path graph (in general for a tree) with $n$ vertices has chromatic polynomial 
$$P(P_j,t)=t(t-1)^{n-1}.$$
Hence
$$P(G,t)=t(t-1)^2\left[(t-1)^2-2(t-1)+1\right]=t(t-1)^2(t-2)^2. $$

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the deletion-contraction algorithm given in
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial

Answer (score 3):

Given a palette of $x$ colors, there are $x$ ways to color the middle vertex, then $x-1$ choices for the upper left vertex, $x-2$ for the lower left, $x-1$ for the upper right, $x-2$ for the lower right, so $x(x-1)^2(x-2)^2$.